# Eloquent - global condition on joining table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have multiple (related) eloquent models, and **most** (not all) of those has field `tenant_id`.
Since tenant condition must always be present on every query and every join, I don't want to leave this to programmer each time, but want to add a global join conditions for specific models.

For global `where` conditions I already have it handled in own abstract model:

```
public static function boot()
{
    if (in_array(HasTenant::class, class_uses(static::class))) { // check if has trait
        static::addGlobalScope('tenant', function (Builder $builder) {
            $tenantId = 1; // this is dynamic
            $builder->where($builder->getModel()->getTable() . '.tenant_id', $tenantId);
        });
    }
}
```

Then, for example, a have `score` table, joined with `customer` - both tables have `tenant_id` field.

Query code:

```
return (new ScoreDatabaseModel())
            ->with('driver')
```

Code for joining driver table:

```
public function driver()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(DriverDatabaseModel::class, 'driver_id');
}
```

Which produces SQL:

```
select *
from `score`
left join `driver` on `driver`.`id` = `score`.`driver_id`
where `score`.`tenant_id` = 1
```

What I would like is to add condition to every join whose model has `tenant_id field` (denoted by HasTenant trait), to add tenant_id condition and produce SQL like:

```
select *
from `score`
left join `driver` on `driver`.id = `score`.`driver_id` AND `driver`.`tenant_id` = 1
where `score`.`tenant_id` = 1
```

Comment: I think you'll have to do it manually

Comment: Are you joining the related tables on manually or are you using Eloquent relationships?

Comment: @Rwd I would like to do it using relationships, if possible. But until now, I haven't found a way, so I'm currently doing it manually.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are joining the table?

Comment: @mrhn added code for joining